# Limiting distribution of $G_n(X_n)$

Tags: convergence, cumulative-distribution-function

Consider two sequences of random variables. At each point in the sequence $X_n \sim F_n$ and $Y_n \sim G_n$, and let $F_n(t)$ and $G_n(t)$ denote their respect CDFs. The distributions $(F_n, G_n)$ are not guaranteed to be continous.

Suppose that both random variables converge to the same limiting distribution. Formally, as $n \to \infty$, $X_n \to^d Z \sim H$ and $Y_n \to^d Z \sim H$, where $H(t)$ is a strictly increasing, continuous function.

Can we show that $G_n(X_n)$ converges to a uniform? If not, can we find a counter-example?

Answer (score 4):

Since $G_n(r) \leqslant 1$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$, this function is "dominated" by the unit function over its entire domain.  This allows us to apply the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to move the limit inside the probability operator.  Taking any value $0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$ we then have:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} [ G_n(X_n) \leqslant t ]
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg[ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} G_n(X_n) \leqslant t \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg[ H(Z) \leqslant t \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= t, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

which proves pointwise convergence to the uniform.

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting idea. How do you prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} G_n(X_n) \to H(Z)$?

Comment: That convergence is not true (since both sides are random variables) but they converge *in distribution* so the probabilities pertaining to those events are the same.

Comment: Is it necessary for $G_n$ to converge uniformly to $H$?

Comment: I believe that pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence for CDFs (see e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670030/)).

Comment: That's a good point, thanks!